# How to I combine Page-views for a URL when they have different query strings in Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to do some reporting on page views on a site and the results are being listed like  the following:

- www.example.com/directory/ - 100 views
- www.example.com/directory/?id=123456 - 10 views
- www.example.com/directory/?id=987654 - 5 views

What filter do I need to create to views the results as:

- www.example.com/directory/ - 100 views
- www.example.com/directory/?id=* - 15 views

Thanks in advance

Comment: regex is correct keyword, have you tried it?

Comment: No regex necessary, simply add "id" to the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" settings in the admin interface for your view.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the above question

Answer (score 6):

Yes, getting historical grouped together is going to mean using something like [Google Docs](http://drive.google.com), [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/), [Tableau Software](http://www.tableausoftware.com), [Analytics Canvas](http://www.analyticscanvas.com), etc.

Moving forward...

One of the simplest ways of keeping things grouped in GA is to set up an advanced profile filter. You'll want to use this with a new profile; keeping a "raw" or "empty" profile is highly advisable for when you actually want to look at those individual URLs.

That said, here's a filter pattern that should work for you:

Go to **Admin** > **Filters** (under the View Column)

**+ New Filter** > **Create new Filter** > **Name it**

Filter Type = **Custom filter** > **Advanced**

Here's the pattern:

**Field A:** `www\.example\.com\/directory\/\?id=.+`
**Output To:** `www\.example\.com\/directory\/\?id=\*`

[image]

Comment: To make things even cleaner, you could wrap the URI you want to keep in parenthesis and then use [notation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en).
**Field A -> Extract A:** `(www\.example\.com\/directory\/\?id=).+`
**Output To -> Constructor:** `$A1`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to aggregate the same URI with multiple query strings is to change the primary dimension to 'Page Title' under Behavior > Site Content > All Pages.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this for your historical data is unfortunately in an excel pivot table.  You can get in in the UI, but only by creating a custom report and searching for very specific directories.

Check out the documentation on excluding query strings in your GA profile. Maybe create a new profile and write an advanced rule to rewrite all "id" pages to "/directory/product-page".

Answer (score 1):

A totally different approach is to use [custom variables](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1144414?hl=en) or [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) and to stop looking in the normal "Behavior" reports section (used to be called "Content" in GA) – custom dims are available using Google Analytics Universal Analytics only, which means starting a new web property and possibly running both code snippets concurrently (totally safe to do).

Personally I find custom dimensions a bit easier to work with than custom variables, and I generally think that it's a good idea to start exploring the new Google Analytics.

The nice thing about either of these approaches is that you can still keep the full page path date in the same profile as your custom dimension / variables information; it'll stay in the Behavior section where it belongs with all the other page paths.

Where I'm going with this...

You can create a new dimension such as "page type" and then call it "products", "posts", "articles", or whatever these id #s represent in this /directory/; then you can look at metrics across the dimension like pageviews, time on page, etc. by page type.

You can even create other dimensions to help describe them in more detail, such as breaking down blog posts or products into their different categories; i.e. hierarchical dimensions. Once you start using this kind of thing you may wonder what you ever did without it!

I think it's fair that I stop this answer now since it's not about how to set up custom variables or custom dimensions; those links should get you started (it's really not difficult).

Note: You can use php to fill in the dimension information in the GA tracking snippet dynamically based on the page that is being viewed (again, that's another question).